# Could Pepper Potts have saved the person who snapped at the end of "Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, iron-man-3

Could Pepper Potts have saved Tony when he snapped at the end of *Avengers: Endgame* due to her regeneration powers from *Iron Man 3* or do the Infinity Stones somehow override her regeneration powers?

Comment: Pepper forgot there was the Iron fleet... Oops wrong franchise!

Comment: There's no indication that Pepper could regenerate anyone except herself..plus Tony cured her later...I think that's stated in the IM3 movie

Comment: Even someone as powerful as The Hulk couldn’t regenerate from the snap; how can Pepper? Moreover, she all the Extremis was taken out of her system at the end of IM3

Comment: I don't see how all the downvotes are warranted here? It's a fair, specific, non-opinion based question in terms of effectively answering (and one where the in-universe answer was only very briefly given at the end of Iron Man 3 and could easily be missed too).

Answer (score 13):

No, she couldn’t have.

It’s briefly stared at the end of the Iron Man 3 movie, that Tony removes the Extremis from Pepper’s system.

And even if that removal was unsuccessful- there’s not any evidence in the MCU that I’m aware of, which suggests Extremis regeneration is transferable like that and capable of healing anyone but whose system it’s pumped into.

Pepper would only be able to heal Pepper.

Comment: It's ironic, isn't it? She could save others from death, but not herself.